# How can I embed a swf object in a vb.net winform?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, flash, embedded-resource

I have a swf object that I would like to embed using the COM Shockwave Flash Object control. I've searched around, but I've only found answers that involve using file or internet URLs. As I am using the One-Click publishing method, I would like to have a way to embed my flash object *as a resource file* into my application.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar in the past but loading from a DB table rather than a resource

Swf is a AxShockwaveFlash Object on the Form to display the flash item.

If you add your resource as a .swf and set the FileType to binary it should return it as a byte array which you can then use in the memorystream constructor

```
Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(my.resources.TheFlashFile), fs As New IO.MemoryStream()
                Using bwriter As New IO.BinaryWriter(fs)
                    ' Write length of stream for flash AxHost.State 
                    bwriter.Write(8 + ms.ToArray.Length)
                    bwriter.Write(&H55665566)
                    ' Length of flash movie file 
                    bwriter.Write(ms.ToArray.Length)
                    bwriter.Write(ms.ToArray)
                    fs.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
                    swf.OcxState = New AxHost.State(fs, 1, False, Nothing)
                End Using
            End Using
```

Comment: If my swf object is in `My.Resources.TheFlashFile`, how would I embed it?

Comment: I've updated the answer above, you just need to add a axShockwaveFlash object to your form and set the name to swf.

Comment: I have three videos I switch between in the same control; I've discovered that many properties of the AxShockwaveFlash object (Quality and Menu, for starters) are reset upon switching.